# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'transcripts/louis.txt'

Tags: python, web-scraping, nlp, jupyter-notebook

I have been trying to scraping 12 scripts and wanted to pickle them but some reason its not working and giving error of [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'transcripts/louis.txt'.
Could some one help me please. Many thanks in advance.

Web scraping, pickle imports

```
    import requests

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    import pickle

    import os

import errno
```

## Scrapes transcript data from scrapsfromtheloft.com

```
def url_to_transcript(url):

    '''Returns transcript data specifically from scrapsfromtheloft.com.'''

    page = requests.get(url).text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

    text = [p.text for p in soup.find(class_="post-content").find_all('p')]


    print(url)

    return text
```

## URLs of transcripts in scope

```
urls = ['http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2017/05/06/louis-ck-oh-my-god-full-transcript/',

        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2017/04/11/dave-chappelle-age-spin-2017-full-transcript/',

        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2018/03/15/ricky-gervais-humanity-transcript/',

        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2017/08/07/bo-burnham-2013-full-transcript/',

        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2017/05/24/bill-burr-im-sorry-feel-way-2014-full-transcript/',

        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2017/04/21/jim-jefferies-bare-2014-full-transcript/',

        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2017/08/02/john-mulaney-comeback-kid-2015-full-transcript/',

        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2017/10/21/hasan-minhaj-homecoming-king-2017-full-transcript/',

        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2017/09/19/ali-wong-baby-cobra-2016-full-transcript/',

        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2017/08/03/anthony-jeselnik-thoughts-prayers-2015-full-transcript/',

        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2018/03/03/mike-birbiglia-my-girlfriends-boyfriend-2013-full-transcript/',

        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2017/08/19/joe-rogan-triggered-2016-full-transcript/']

# Comedian names
comedians = ['louis', 'dave', 'ricky', 'bo', 'bill', 'jim', 'john', 'hasan', 'ali', 'anthony', 'mike', 'joe']
```

## # Actually request transcripts (takes a few minutes to run)

```
transcripts = [url_to_transcript(u) for u in urls]
```

## # Pickle files for later use

## # Make a new directory to hold the text files

## !mkdir transcripts

```
for i, c in enumerate(comedians):

    with open("transcripts/" + c + ".txt", "wb") as file:

        pickle.dump(transcripts[i], file)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------


 FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

    <ipython-input-6-f3ce7b5495e7> in <module>
          5 
          6 for i, c in enumerate(comedians):

    ----> 7     with open("transcripts/" + c + ".txt", "wb") as file:

          8         pickle.dump(transcripts[i], file)

    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'transcripts/louis.txt'`**enter code here**`
```

Comment: Do you have a folder called transcripts? If not, I think that's your problem.

Comment: My guess is that you're using a relative path to the file, and the current working directory is different than what you expected. We don't have enough information to confirm that, though.

Comment: Hi Guys, Appreciate your time to answer. i have found the problem and it was Transcript/ where it should be only transcript. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is your working directory? Run `os.getcwd()` to find out. The folder structure you wish to use needs to be in there.